# TDMA and FDMA based slot assignment protocol in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I need to implement TDMA and FDMA based slot assignment protocol. I have written the code for TDMA slot assignment but very much confused about the FDMA part.
Will someone please help me in writing the code for FDMA for a simple scenario. In which two nodes are using full duplex radios and working on two different frequencies. If node1 needs to communicate to node 2 thn node 2 must shift its frequency to node 1 frequency.
I have not worked with the radios yet. In TDMA part i am using senddirect for sending messages.
Kindly help me with the code of FDMA?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple radios in a single host. A good starting point is the example in inet path `examples/manetrouting/multiradio`. Run the simulation configuration [MultiRadio](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/examples/manetrouting/multiradio/omnetpp.ini#L44) within `omnetpp.ini`.

Comment: Kindly tell me Why should i need multiple radios in single module? Don't we have a single full duplex radio provided in inet? 
Besides i have checked the multiRadio example in inet and it has three configurations. Which one you have suggested me to begin with?


[Config IndependentWlans]
description = "Two independent WLANs on different radio channels"


[Config SwitchedWlans]
description = "APs connected via an Ethernet switch"


[Config RoutedWlans]
description = "Two WLANs connected via a router with two wireless NICs"

Comment: Above, I added a link to the corresponding config.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am working with adhoc networks and wants to do it with single full duplex radio in one node/module. How can i do it?